# How to get the caller's user id in an impersonated procedure?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, sql-server-2008-r2

If you write  a procedure with "execute as xxx", is it possible to retrieve  the original user, who called the procedure, somehow within the procedure ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Does `ORIGINAL_LOGIN()` return the information you're after?

http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189492.aspx

Comment: Yes, `ORIGINAL_LOGIN` is the way to go. I have used it numerous times now, even in scenarios where different user rights were nested.

Answer (score 0):

As per the documentation, you use EXECUTE AS CALLER:

EXECUTE AS CALLER;
SELECT user_name(); -- Shows execution context is set to SqlUser2, the caller of the module.
REVERT;

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/execute-as-clause-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver16